# Spring boot jar app searches for static resources in invalid directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-applications, resources

I checked many topic, but still have this issue.

```
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/back.office/", "/resources/front.office/");
}
```

I am trying to access

```
http://localhost:8080/static/index.html
```

But during this I see requests to

```
 http://localhost:8080/static/favicon.ico
```

Located here

```
 \src\main\resources\front.office\resources\templates\generic\img\favicon.ico
```

How fix this?

Comment: This run in debug mode, without jar.

Comment: Tries also registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:back.office/", "classpath:front.office/");

Comment: `src/main/resources` is not part of the classpath; your locations should just start at `front.office`. Spring is failing to find *anything* at those resource locations and proceeding to check elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content), static content will be served from these locations (`/static`, `/public`, `/resources` and `/META-INF/resources`) in classpath.

I would suggest you create one directory inside resources (`/src/main/resources`) named as `public` ('/src/main/resources/public/') and keep your static content there and register like this.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
   .addResourceLocations({"classpath:/resources/","classpath:/static/", 
             "classpath:/public/","classpath:/META-INF/resources/"};
```

In your case, you can have `favicon.ico` just inside public (/src/main/resources/public/favicon.ico) and should be accessible like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/static/favicon.ico
```

if you have a file like `/src/main/resources/public/x/y/z/abc.pqr`, then it should be accessible like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/static/x/y/z/abc.pqr
```

I hope this helps.